# MySQL: Count results of subquery and still use the set it returns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

The question is how to find the total number of rows that an inner query returned, but still use the set retuned by the inner query (without repeating the same query twice).

I have a query:

```
SELECT a1.name as name
FROM
(
    SELECT b1.id as id
    FROM b1 JOIN b2 JOIN b3 ...
    WHERE b1.x = ... AND ...
) as ids
JOIN a1 ON a1.id = ids.id
JOIN a2 ON a2.id = ids.id AND ...
JOIN a3 ON a3.id = ids.id AND ...
WHERE a1.name = 'apple' AND a2.name = 'orange' AND a3.name = 'pear'
UNION
SELECT the same query but with 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse'
UNION
SELECT the same query but with 'python', 'perl', 'java'
ORDER BY name
```

with a number of tables and complicated conditions, where the set of IDs is selected in a subquery.

I want to know two different things:

- the values selected by the large query, which uses the set of specific IDs
- the number of IDs selected by the inner subquery: how many IDs were considered, even if not matched in the outer query.

The tables are large, so the question is not about how to find the info, but how to do it efficiently.

Say, executing the inner query twice, once as a subquery and once only for counting, would probably be too slow.

Can I find both types of info in one query?

The ORDER of names is independent from IDs, so I guess I cannot GROUP BY a1.id an thus cannot use COUNT DISTINCT a1.id.

Comment: Could you just do `select b1.id as id, count(*) as reccount...where...group by id` for the inner query? You should then be able to use the count from inner query as you desire.

Comment: @zedfoxus If I tested it correctly, when I used `count(*)` the inner query gave only one row. Can this be true? Sounds plausible because to find the `count(*)` it needs to work until the last row is found.

Comment: It can result in 1 row if there is only 1 ID in the table. Otherwise, it should give you unique ID and their count. If you are familiar with sqlfiddle.com, I'd recommend creating a table structure with dummy data and edit your post with the link and expected results. It'll help in answering the question

Comment: Yes, will make a fiddle. Let me test Gordon's answer first, maybe it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, and it doesn't answer your questions (which I don't really understand).  But, why are you using `union`?  Just have a single `where` clause for all the conditions:

```
WHERE (a1.name = 'apple' AND a2.name = 'orange' AND a3.name = 'pear') or
      (a1.name = 'cat' AND a2.name = 'dog' AND a3.name = 'mouse') or
      (a1.name = 'python' AND a2.name = 'perl' AND a3.name = 'java')
```

If you want the number selected by the inner query, the following should work:

```
SELECT a1.name as name, @num as NumberSelected
FROM (SELECT b1.id as id, @num := @num + 1
      FROM b1 JOIN b2 JOIN b3 ... CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num := 0) params
      WHERE ...
     )  ids
```

The subquery should be evaluated before the outer query, so the value of `@num` should be correct.

Comment: I use UNION because otherwise the JOINs grow explosively, I think. At least testing shows that with OR it's orders of magnitude slower. And I indicated that I have to use UNION precisely because then I cannot use @num++. Or, is there any way to reset @num somehow before each UNION? Then this would be the answer!

Comment: OOPS, probably dividing your @num by the number of UNIONs would give the answer? Will test this now.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh . . . You would need a separate variable for each of the `union` subqueries.

Comment: Yes, but I think this would invalidate caching, so it will be equivalent to do the subquery many times. Now it works well with UNION because, I think, the inner query is cached. Not sure if `@num` will invalidate caching, too. Will test and let you know.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh - The Query cache is probably useless; the buffer_pool is useful for caching.